# In pandas and matplotlib, why is plt not called directly on the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

It's not clear to me why plotting is done like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.boxplot(column='initial_cost', by='Borough', rot=90)

plt.show()
```

How is the dataframe tied to plt.show()? I've done a few web searches and even took a look at the documentation(!) but couldn't find anything addressing this specifically.

I would expect something more like:

```
boxplot = df.boxplot(column='initial_cost', by='Borough', rot=90)
plt.show(boxplot)
```

Or even something like this:

```
boxplot = df.boxplot(column='initial_cost', by='Borough', rot=90)
boxplot.plt.show()
```

Comment: All about that [namespace](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#module-matplotlib.pyplot).

Comment: when you call the `df.boxplot()` function, you are instantiating an matplotlib ax-object [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.0/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L2249-L2259). All that does is just create ax object. the `plt.show()` function is used to visualize instances of existing `ax` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matplotlib provides a `MATLAB`-like *state-machine*, the `pyplot` module, that takes care under the hood of instantiating and managing all the objects you need to draw a plot.

Pandas hooks into that in the same fashion. When you call it takes care of loading `pyplot` and creating a matplotlib [`Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html), [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html), several [`Line2D`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) objects and everything that makes a boxplot.

When you call `plt.show()` it will track all the figures you created with the state-machine API, create a GUI with those figures and take care of displaying it.

If you need more control, you can of course do it all yourself with the object-oriented API. Create a figure, axes, manually draw the canvas, it's all there if needed.

As far as I've seen the common practice is a mix of both: hook into the object-oriented API when needed but still let `pyplot` take care of displaying or saving everything to a file.